# Excel: Remove part of text string if a match is found in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of data with the company name and address. However in the address column, the company name is joined with the address. I want to know if it is possible to compare these 2 columns and remove the company name from the address.

See attached pic
[image]

Comment: it it always at the beginning if it matches?

Comment: Does "Company Name" actually contain `1.` , `2.` etc ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

paste this into cell c2

```
IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(A2,B2,1)),B2,RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-LEN(A2)))
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

in column C use:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(B2,Right(A2,len(A2)-find(" ",A2)),""))
```

- The RIGHT function will strip off the leading number.
- The SUBSTITUTE function replaces what is left of A2 that is found in B2 with nothing.
- The TRIM function removes the leading space.

---

### Update

Just to be on the safe side in case there might be more than one space between the "." and the start of the name, or trailing spaces in the name.

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(B2,TRIM(Right(A2,len(A2)-find(" ",A2))),""))
```

Added a TRIM function to what is being pulled from column A.

Comment: Just a friendly and humble opinion. In this formula ~find(" ",A2)~ will find and give location of first space whereas what we require is the location of second space i.e. after David Comp. Since I am at basic level in formulas, I thought it reasonable to point out my view point for confirmation.

Comment: @skkakkar Actually I want it to find the first space.  I did make the assumption that there were no spaces in front of the numbers.  The reason is I then take all the text after the space in A2 and replace that trimed text where it is found in B2 with "".  Some of the other approaches were taking the right side of B2 and retruning the number of character len(b2) - number of character from A1 that would match.  lots of ways to do it.

Comment: I get it. nicely explained.

Comment: @skkakkar Throw this one out at you, what happens when the company name is only one word or more than 2 words? admittedly that was not in the example data.

Comment: @skkakkar  I did not mean to scare you with that last comment!  just wanted to give you food for thought.

Comment: I appreciate our professional approach. It has really set my thought process to look for worst case scenarios any such situation. Heartfelt Thanks.

Comment: @skkakkar Yes and no,  Best practice is absolutely put all the time and energy in the world to make sure the thing works for you needs.  So if you know you have structured data and there is no way the company name can be anything other than two names, then you do not need to worry about catching other possibilities.  Sometimes knowing you don't have to worry about certain scenarios can simply your formula or code.  As for on here,  some days I would say style your answer to match the level of effort put into the question.

Answer (score 1):

In C2 and fill down:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(B2,MID(A2,SEARCH(". ",A2,1)+2,500),""))
```

Answer (score 0):

So many options!

```
=RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-IFERROR(FIND(A1,B1,1),0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one from my side

```
=MID(B1,(LEN(A1)+2),99)
```

[image: snapshot showing results]